# Spring + Hibernate + TestNG + Mockito cannot cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: spring, hibernate, testng

I'm trying to write unit test for my app. Test need to use data from sql file. Maven gives me exeption

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c65a0afd cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
```

Hibernate DataSource configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

TestConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:test-context.xml")
public class TestConfiguration {

}
```

test-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">


<!-- Set up H2 database -->
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:import.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

I can't find the answer, or a proper example. And the most important, when i delete tests, app works fine.

**UPDATE**

Stack trace

https://jpst.it/PY4v

Comment: Where exactly does the exception happen? Show us the stack trace and relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the bean with id `dataSource` as a data source (i.e. you inject it to a field expecting `javax.sql.DataSource`), but it's not a datasource, it's a `EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean` which implements `FactoryBean<DataSource>`.

You need to call [`FactoryBean.getObject()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html#getObject--) when injecting it into `entityManagerFactory` bean, possibly by something like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="...">
    <property name="...">
        <bean factory-bean="dataSource" factory-method="getObject" />
    </property>
</bean>
```